# Debian jessie boot hangs at "Started Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes."

Tags: debian, boot, cpu

I just upgraded my MOBO and CPU on my PC, and now whenever I try and boot my debian install it hangs at `[  OK  ] Started Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes.` Is there an way I can boot into my old setup with my new hardware without having to completely reinstall?

Specs:

- CPU = AMD Phenom II 965 3.4 Ghz x4 -> AMD FX 8350 4.0 Ghz x8
- MOBO = ASUS M4A87TD EVO -> ASUS M5A99FX PRO

Comment: http://www.adonespitogo.com/articles/fixed-starting-update-utmp-about-system-runlevel-changes-error-in-kali-invidia-installation/

Answer (score 17):

There is probably a problem with your video driver. I resolved it by following (modified) instructions at http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2072420:

- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to switch to a new console
- `sudo apt-get purge xserver-xorg-video-intel` then reboot
- `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel`
- `nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf`, remove any present code (if applicable) and enter the following:

  ```
  Section "Device" 
      Identifier "Card0"
      Driver "intel" 
      Option "AccelMethod" "sna" 
  EndSection
  ```
- Save the file and reboot

Comment: Had same message on boot, fixed it only with the `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel` part (didn't have the intel xserver installed nor any xorg.conf file)

Comment: It does happen in other situations too, I'm seeing it trying to make my Raspberry Pi do an autologin for some automated testing. I won't claim to understand it, but it doesn't always point to a video problem.

Comment: Thanks for these instructions!  Fixed the problem with `purge` and `install` - didn't have to edit xorg.conf.

Answer (score 2):

`Bas van dongen`'s answer pointed me in the right direction, although in my case it was the nvidia driver that was failing.

First run `nvidia-installer --uninstall`.

Then follow [these instructions](https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers#Debian_8_.22Jessie.22) for reinstalling the nvidia driver on Jessie

1. Add `jessie-backports` to your `/etc/apt/sources.list`, for example:

   ```
   # jessie-backports
   deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main contrib non-free
   ```
2. Install Linux headers for the kernel you are using.

   For example, if you are using the 3.16 Linux kernel in Debian Jessie:

   ```
   apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,')
   ```

   Or if you are already using a Linux kernel from jessie-backports:

   ```
   apt-get install -t jessie-backports linux-headers-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,')
   ```
3. Then we can install the package nvidia-driver.

   ```
   apt-get update
   apt-get install -t jessie-backports nvidia-driver
   ```
4. Restart your system to enable the nouveau blacklist.

See [this bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=856355) for more information

Comment: I had a similar Nvidia Driver issue to this after `apt dist-upgrade`. I fixed this with `aptitude install nvidia-driver-460` and made it remove whatever it "upgraded" to.