# Can't boot kali linux first time (dual boot) UTMP; TMDS & ACPI errors

Tags: kali-linux, grub2, grub, acpi

After installing (which I have done 15 times over and over so far, with different installers) I don't know anymore what to do.

With normal booting in kali (no extra GRUB parameters) I get the following errors:

```
[12.091617] tpm_crp MSFT0101:00: [Firmware Bug]: ACPI region does not cover t
[12.091655] tpm_crp MSFT0101:00: [Firmware Bug]: ACPI region does not cover t
[15.882542] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: Pointer to TMDS table invalid
```

Upon seeing that nouveau error I searched a little bit online and appended `nomodeset nouveau.modeset=0 nvidia.modeset=0` at the command list.

Now it is not giving me the errors anymore, but it gives this:

```
Starting UTMP about System Runlevel Changes
```

Does anybody know what I have to do or can somebody explain this situation?

P.S. Some info:

I already have kali on my VM, but that is not very efficient for the memory.

After the errors it just freezes. Sometimes the screen goes black with a not moving white underscore, sometimes it's blinking and once in 15 minutes it says "`wlan0: link is not ready`" or "`wlan0: link becomes ready`". I already left my laptop on for a full 24 hours, still no effect.

I have no internet connection since I didn't boot yet. So any solution featuring any sort of `apt` or any other internet connection dependant thing will not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a Kali user, this is just a suggestion of something to try much more than an out right answer.

Given that Kali is based on Debian there's a reasonable chance of sharing boot issues. 
 There's an answer (here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/255583/20140 ) which points to issues with graphics drivers.

---

You do have access to get an unbootable system in contact with the internet:

1. Build a live Linux USB or CD (NOT Kali!).  If you can't think of another then download and burn an Ubuntu installer, it has the option to "try Ubuntu" which boots into a fully working Linux desktop.
2. Boot your live USB or CD and connect to your internet
3. Mount your Kali partition (eg to `/mnt`)
4. Bind-mount live `/dev` `/sys` `/proc` to their respective Kali locations (eg: `mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev`).
5. Edit Kali's `resolv.conf` so that it has a valid name server (eg: add the line `nameserver 8.8.8.8` to `/mnt/etc/resolv.conf`)
6. chroot into your mounted Kali (eg: `chroot /mnt /bin/bash`)

Now you're at your Kali command line with fully working network! :-)

Comment: I am not an advanced linux user, but, I am not a beginner. Kind of in between. I said I am experienced, because on the previous post I made (also again my graphics card) there was 1 person who said as an answer "yeah just dont use kali" (in a more formal way). I do understand what you are saying. I gave it an upvote because I find the first answer very smart, but I am not sure if this will resolve the issue. I will try. Thanks

Comment: PS; the second answer is also smart. Thank you :D

Comment: @Sam That's fine. Apologies, I was a little too pointed in my remarks.  We're all here to learn.  Yes the chroot trick has saved me may times.  It's worth knowing.  If you ever do feel that Kali has beaten you back, then consider trying Arch linux.  It still requires significant Linux skill to use but has a [better wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/)